# PHP Error In Syntax: "to use near '-3, 3"

Tags: php, pdo, pagination

I'm following [a tutorial](https://www.codeofaninja.com/2013/06/simple-php-pagination-script.html) but it seems I'm either doing something wrong, or the tutorial is outdated.

The tutorial told me to run this query:

```
$recordsPerPage = 3;
$fromRecordNum = ($recordsPerPage * $page) - $recordsPerPage;

$query = $engine->runQuery("SELECT * FROM forum_posts ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $fromRecordNum, $recordsPerPage WHERE topic_id=:topic");
$query->execute(array(':topic'=>$thread['id']));
```

But this appears to output this error:

> Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]:
>   Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL
>   syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server
>   version for the right syntax to use near '-3, 3 WHERE topic_id='20''
>   at line 1'

I've tried looking up different tuturials about pagination but it seems they all use this technique.

I hope someone knows how to fix this! Thanks a lot!!

Comment: that code is asking for sql injection!!!

Comment: @DanielA.White Do you mean my version or the code in the tutorial?

Comment: this code here.

Comment: RTM https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html

Comment: You need to format your query differently, move WHERE clause before ORDER BY

Comment: @DanielA.White Why would hardcoded code be vulnerable to sql injection?

Comment: Needs to be  `SELECT * FROM forum_posts WHERE topic_id=:topic ...`

Comment: why did this receive an upvote? it's a typo question

Comment: Oh never mind. LIMIT {[offset,] row_count | row_count OFFSET offset, it does accept offset as optional parameter

Comment: @user3647971 That seems to fix it, thanks a lot!